# Pubnub PHP SDK subscribe function

Tags: php, pubnub

I'm working on a chat application using PubNub and PHP. The publishing of messages is working but I'm not sure how to read from the subscriber.

I ran the subscriber file in the command line and it is showing the messages as they are published but I'm not sure how to read from it or how to return, as per the doc the subscriber is a separate process.

```
use PubNub\PNConfiguration;

class MySubscribeCallback extends SubscribeCallback {
    function status($pubnub, $status) {
        if ($status->getCategory() === PNStatusCategory::PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory) {
            // This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost
        } else if ($status->getCategory() === PNStatusCategory::PNConnectedCategory) {

        } else if ($status->getCategory() === PNStatusCategory::PNDecryptionErrorCategory) {
            // Handle message decryption error. Probably client configured to
            // encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.
        }
    } 

    function message($pubnub, $message) {
        print_r($pubnub);
        print_r($message);
    }

    function presence($pubnub, $presence) {
        // handle incoming presence data
    }
}

$subscribeCallback = new MySubscribeCallback();

$pubnub->addListener($subscribeCallback);
$pubnub->subscribe()
           ->channels(["Channel-1","Channel-2","Channel-3"])
           ->execute();
```

this is the subscriber code present on the PubNub Doc.
I'm calling this file using javascript.

Comment: you want to receive the messages in your JS web client, right? If so, don't subscribe from your PHP server, rather, subscribe directly from your JS web app. Your PHP server can serve the JS code that does the subscribe to your client. In other words, your server should never need to subscribe to PubNub. And the client can also publish directly to PubNub so your server doesn't need to do that either. Make sense?

Comment: By the way, can you share the link where you got this sample code from? It may need to be updated to say what I just said above.

Comment: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/php  this is the doc link